# Steht ein Nomen, nach dem eine Reihung steht, im Plural?

Tags: grammar-identification, list

> Die Funktionen der Beispiele Hans, Tom, Lukas, Erik sind wichtig.

Ist hier "der Beispiele" oder "des Beispiels" richtig?
Ich verstehe es so, dass "Hans, Tom, ..." eine Apposition ist, welche wiederum aus
Satzgliedteilen besteht, also dass es keine zusammengezogenen Sätze sind.
Zu Subjekten, die aus Satzgliedteilen in Reihung bestehen, habe ich im Duden gefunden:

> Die Reihung gilt gesamthaft als Plural.

Es wäre eine weitere Frage, ob dieselben Regeln (welche es auch sein mögen) gelten würden, wenn das Genitivattribut das
Subjekt wäre.

Answer (score 1):

Die Tatsache, dass "Beispiel(e)" durch eine Apposition näher bestimmt ist, hat eigentlich keine Auswirkung auf den Numerus. Die Frage ist nur, ob es sich um *ein* Beispiel oder um *mehrere* Beispiele handelt (es ist vorstellbar, dass es sich bei "Hans, Tom, Lukas,..." z.B. um *ein* Beispiel sozialer Interaktion dieser Personen untereinander handelt, oder aber um mehrere Beispiele von Personen)

Hast du *ein* Beispiel, nimm den Singular.

Hast du mehrere Beispiele, nimm den Plural.

Comment: Weil Hans, Tom und Lukas aber jeweils ein eigenes Beispiel sind, nehme ich demnach Plural?

Comment: Wenn sie das sind, dann ja.